# Map table row to DDD value object woith EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

**scenario**

I have two aggregates in my microservice Domain model: User and UserNotification.

```
public class User : Aggreagete
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class UserNotification : Aggreagete
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public int UserId { get; private set; }

    public bool EnableSms { get; private set; }

    public bool EnableEmail { get; private set; }

    public NotificationKind NotificationKind { get; private  set; }

    public UserModel User { get;private set }
}
```

UserValueObject needs to be mapped from the same table as User Aggregate. I use UserValueObject because from Notification bounded Context it needs to be immutable.

I have following EF mappings:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users", SCHEME);

        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        builder.Property(o => o.Id);

        builder.HasMany<UserNotification>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(entry => entry.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserNotification> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserNotifications", SCHEME);

        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        builder.Property(o => o.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.EnableSms).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.EnableEmail).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.NotificationKind).IsRequired()
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                strValue => Enum.Parse<NotificationKind>(strValue)
            );
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.User).ToTable("Users");
    }
```

**problem**

I receive error during "Add Migration"

```
Cannot use table 'dbo.Users' for entity type 'User' since it is being used for entity type 'UserModel' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.
```

UserModel is:

```
public class UserModel : ValueObject
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Phone { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

**question**

I would like to map UserModel.Id from database table "Users", but Email, Phone and Name should be injected in repository with using HTTP request to Identity 
Service. Is is possible to do such operation with EF core?
I see that it is not possible to achieve this with owned entity, because Users table is used also to mapped other aggreagate.

Comment: If it's immutable, why do you want to create a FK using that `UserModel User` property? Just thinking if it wouldn't make more sense to just create the properties you need to be immutable as part of the `UserNotification` entity.

Comment: Owned entity has foreign key behind and is often used to implement Value object pattern from DDD. But in my scneario I also want to use User table to other aggregate in different context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the correct exception due to the name conflict.

For the `User` entity you ask EF to use the `Users` table:

```
builder.ToTable("Users", SCHEME);
```

but you also ask it to use the same table to store value objects of the `UserNotification` entity:

```
builder.OwnsOne(e => e.User).ToTable("Users");
```

If your plan is to "reuse" the `Users` aggregate persistence to magically map the value project to it than I can definitely tell that it's not a good idea.

Value objects are typed pieces of state. They belong to entities and managed by entities. You have to update the content of the VO when needed.

You also don't need to keep the user information in the aggregate, unless you use it in any of the methods of your notification aggregate. If you need to be able to query and join - just do that in the query. Don't use EF for queries and write a plain SQL with inner join to get the information you need. Look up CQRS, Jimmy Bogard advocated using EF for the write side and plain SQL queries for the read side some time ago, it makes total sense.

Comment: In some scenarios there is possible to map aggregate B to value object in aggreagte B and it is correct in DDD. I need user email, phone etc. to use in notification to send it ;). Thank for Bogard articles I will read it.

Comment: I cannot agree with the fact that a value object would be getting the data from a completely different aggregate using son sort of magic ORM trick. I am entirely unsure how this can be ”correct”. An aggregate I the consistency boundary on it's own. It owns it's state entirely.

Comment: aggregate is domain model. Data is in sql table and can be mapped to both aggregate A and value object in aggregate B. EF does not offer this kind of behaviour. It is possible for entity